# VBA: Refresh an Excel page linked with Nielsen

Tags: vba, excel

I just discovered VBA on Excel and I was wondering if (and how) I could refresh automatically an Excel page linked with a Nielsen base thanks to a VBA code.

I have already succesfully created such a VBA code for an Excel document linked with a VBA base, but i ran out of ideas for that. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for helping!

Your sincerely,

Laurent

Comment: Can you please post, the excel structure and the vba code?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your companies Nielsen contact for the NITRO Components Reference Guide document.  It has examples and code to help you on this.  The code is in vb which you will have to translate to vba (minor differences).

```
Dim acnNitro As New ACNNITRO
Dim acnNitroUpdate As ACNielsenNitro.ACNNitroUpdate
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim bret as Boolean
acnNitro.ParentApp = Application
acnNitroUpdate = acnNitro.ACNNitroUpdate
WS = ActiveSheet 'or Set WS = WorkSheets("My Sheet")
bret = acnNitroUpdate.UpdateAllNRanges(WS, ntrSelectGet)
acnNitro = Nothing
acnNitroUpdate = Nothing
WB = Nothing
```